# sending string in sockets C?

Tags: c, string, bash, sockets

I am trying to send this string:

Server code:

```
char bash[256] = "grep 'usernama' data/*.txt | awk -F':' '{print $1}' | uniq";
char result[1000] = system(bash);
send(connected, result,strlen(result), 0);  
fflush(stdout);
```

Error message:

```
error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
```

Issit possiible to send the grep result to the client in that way?

Comment: You seem to be missing a lot of code.

Comment: @ignacio: Can guide me to the codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this, if you're willing to call `system()` and run a shell, is probably to redirect the output to a file, then open the file, read its contents, and send that.

This of course opens up a bunch of problems (mainly race conditions and error handling), but it can perhaps be a bit simpler than just diving in and learning about `fork()` and `exec()`.

Answer (score 2):

system(3) returns you status of fork(2), but not stdout of forked program. Standard solution is using pipes:

```
char bash_cmd[256] = "grep 'usernama' data/*.txt | awk -F':' '{print $1}' | uniq":
char buffer[1000];
FILE *pipe;
int len;

pipe = popen(bash_cmd, "r");
if (pipe == NULL) {
    perror("pipe");
    exit(1);
}

fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), pipe);
len = strlen(bash_cmd);
bash_cmd[len-1] = '\0';

pclose(pipe);
```

Answer (score 1):

`system` doesn't capture the output from the command it runs, so it isn't possible to do what you want that way.

If you look at the [system man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) you can see it returns `int`, the exit status of the command you run.

In order to capture the output of a process, you need to:

1. Find a library that does it for you.
2. Code up your own fork/exec with pipes implementation.
3. Redirect the output to a temporary file, then read that in. (From [@unwind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283235/sending-string-in-sockets-c/4283709#4283709))

3 would be slightly simpler than 2, but would introduce security and reliability problems that wouldn't be present in 1 or 2.

Comment: So there is no direct and simple way to do it?

Comment: @origame: No simple way from C. Probably easier to either do it all from bash, or switch to a more high-level language such as python.